# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', search a database injection proof

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need a simple search feature to search the database, the examples I found on google are all sql injection prone.

On using this code:

```
SELECT userid, fullname, website, birth, image FROM profile WHERE fullname LIKE ? OR website LIKE ?", %{$_POST["searchname"]}%, %{$_POST["searchurl"]}%
```

I am getting a

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/search.php on line 15
```

Although I found an [example in docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)(Example 6), it uses execute, while in my code, I am calling it as a function.

My query function- [Link to codepad](http://codepad.org/rFvsxLlZ)

My search function -

```
http://codepad.org/pfGZdWW5 (link was not allowed.)
```

Please help me correct it! If you need more information about code, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Put quotes before the first % and after the last

Comment: http://codepad.org/fmBCUzDa, gave Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/search.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare that query:

```
$handle= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = 'SELECT userid, fullname, website, birth, image 
          FROM profile 
          WHERE fullname LIKE ? OR website LIKE ?';

$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$_POST['searchname'].'%', '%'.$_POST['searchurl'].'%'));
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/search.php on line 21 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/search.php on line 21

Comment: @SilentFox `pdo` is the connection object of course

Comment: Yes, in my case its $handle, as defined in the query function, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Instead of creating a new connection, breaking the symmetry, cant I do something like this?     
    $rows = query("SELECT userid, fullname, website, birth, image FROM profile WHERE fullname LIKE ? OR website LIKE ?", "%"+$_POST["searchname"]+"%", "%"+$_POST["searchurl"]+"%");

Comment: You mean ?
`query("SELECT userid, fullname, website, birth, image FROM profile WHERE fullname LIKE ? OR website LIKE ?", '%'.$_POST['searchname'].'%', '%'.$_POST['searchurl'].'%');`
I am not sure how your function works but I showed you the basic

Comment: Yes that! it works, but it returns everything and not the entered string :(

Comment: No this query returns the whole table :( I need it to find specific fullname or url and return it.

Comment: if its specific dont use like use the where clause directly `WHERE fullname = ? OR website = ?`

Comment: That gives a Sorry, no rows found. :(

Comment: what about the first one only:
`"...WHERE fullname = ?";


$stmt->execute(array($_POST['searchname']));`

Comment: Sorry, no rows found.

Comment: No I have to check these two parameters, separately. Because this doesnt work in MySQL workbench.